# SpringMVC - dispatcher servler's url pattern style

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, servlets

I am trying to build a restful style API, using `springMVC`.

When config the url-pattern for springMVC's `DispatcherServlet`, there seems to have 2 choice, and I need some advice.

**Choice A:**
config pattern as: `<url-pattern>*.action</url-pattern>`
and action use path like `@RequestMapping("/role/add.action")`

**Choice B:**
config pattern as: `<url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>`
and action use path like `@RequestMapping("/api/role/add")`

I prefer to use a style that has no suffix, but in that case I need do add a sub path.

But I am not sure which is more proper to use in a project that serve as a backend to provide restful API, with browser / IOS / Android as its client.

---

There might be a **choice C**, but I am not sure:

config pattern as: `<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>`
and action use path like `@RequestMapping("/role/add")`

In this case built-in servlet will be override, e.g jsp won't work normally.
But I don't have any `jsp`, and also, static resource like `html / js / css / image / document / music / video` are all put on another port or server served by `nginx`, request to tomcat only provide ajax service via json data.
So in this case is it proper to use choice C, or it has some bad side-effects?

Comment: I recommend using Spring Boot, which eliminates the need for any such specification.

Comment: @chrylis Can you help to explain a little about how spring boot fix this? Because according to servlet specification, I can't find a pattern that has neither suffix nor sub-path, while could avoiding override the built-in servlets.

Comment: Spring Boot manages the entire container for you, and so you don't have to specify any paths at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if your goal is restful api my choice is the second one since you identify the resource in the url; say you must manage a role resource you should have some mapping like these ones:

```
@RequestMapping("/api/role" method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

to insert a new role (may be the api does not allow this)

```
@RequestMapping("/api/role/{roleId}" method = RequestMethod.PUT)
```

to update an existing role

```
@RequestMapping("/api/role/{roleId}" method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
```

to delete a role

```
@RequestMapping("/api/role" method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

to retrieve roles (you may implement some filters via query string)

The same applies for other resources (User, etc) the naming schema is the same.

I vould avoid option C since I think it's best to have a dedicated mapping for the api if you app also ship a web interface that does not use the api

Answer (score 3):

I will go with the **Choice B** for RESTful services, consider performing `CRUD` operations using `REST`. And you can map the `url-pattern` as ,

```
config pattern as: <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
```

So to perform add , you can just make sure that you post the JSON object from the page and have a url like `/api/add`

And in case of delete , you can simply follow the same . Consider you are going to delete a `object` from the list using its id . You can simply make it out as,

`/api/delete/${id}`

And handle it like ,

```
@RequestMapping(value="/{id}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
```

Comment: Good suggestion, but many api has multiple parameter, so I still need to put parameter after `?` or in http body, I guess.

Comment: Yes it depends on the API too. why dont you use the objects for multiple parameters.

Comment: I use object sometimes, still that also apply to only part of API, e.g a Search service has more parameters from multiple model maybe.