# Getting Error(HTTP Status 404 -) in Spring Mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am new in SpringMVC and trying to execute simple hello world program. However, when run this in my browser (http://localhost:8080/FirstspringMVCwithannotation/welcome) I got HTTP Status- 404 Error. Here, is the code:

HelloController.java

```
package com.example;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.portlet.ModelAndView;


@Controller
public class HelloController {
    @RequestMapping("/welcome")
    public ModelAndView helloWorld(){
        ModelAndView model=new ModelAndView("HelloPage");
        model.addObject("msg","hello world");
        return model;
    }


}
```

web.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>FirstspringMVCwithannotation</display-name>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
                  org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

  <context:component-scan base-package="com.example" />
  <mvc:annotation-driven/> 

  <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" >
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
 </bean>
</beans>
```

HelloPage.jsp

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>
            First Spring MVC Application Demo 
        </h1>   
        <h2>
           ${msg}
        </h2>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is my project structure and I added all spring jar files under lib folder

[image]

I tried to see other solution but that does not solved my problem..can anyone help me please, why i get HTTP Status- 404 Error? Thanks in advance

Comment: Try changing `<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>` to `<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>`, refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29792677

Comment: `@RequestMapping("/welcome")` is the reason for error change it to `/` to work or follow aboive comment

Comment: What is your project file structure? in which folder path your jsp views are located?

Comment: @EricWang  I have tried both but does not work...i am getting HTTP Status 404 - /FirstspringMVCwithannotation/WEB-INF/.jsp what does it mean? tomcat server console says spring servlet initialization is completed..is that controller can not find HelloPage.jsp. However, when I try /welcome console showing this  org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/FirstspringMVCwithannotation/welcome] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring-dispatcher'...

Comment: @MosheArad my jsp file is under WEB-INF

Answer (score 0):

You received HTTP 404 because your dispatcher controller can't find you view.

Your view is under lib folder, which is under WEB-INF folder.

All you need to do is the reconfigure you view resolver, instead of what you wrote:

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" >
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

write it like this: **configure your view resolver to extract views from lib folder**

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">        
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/lib/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

One more thing, I would recommend that you place your jsp files under views folder under WEB-INF and not under lib folder.

lib under WEB-INF is a folder dedicated to 3rd party libraries and jars.

Comment: Actually hello.jsp is in under WEB-INF folder...Now I have changed the eclipse neon to kepler and start fresh project and working with the same code which is running good....I have found one thing there...in screenshot here I have provided did you see a little dot on spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml file but this dot sign is not in kepler project. Is that any version or other problem with eclipse neon?